buyable link url generator is not filling cart apropriatly
edit: I belive the issue is in the base64 and have checked my output against a control string in my working google sheets version and they are diffrent after the base64 encoding i just dont understand why.
control string: {"products":[{"id":"606625996","quantity":"2","options":{"size":"10 inch"}},{"id":"606625996","quantity":"6","options":{"size":"6 inch"}}]}
functioning output:
JTdCJTIycHJvZHVjdHMlMjIlM0ElNUIlN0IlMjJpZCUyMiUzQSUyMjYwNjYyNTk5NiUyMiUyQyUyMnF1YW50aXR5JTIyJTNBJTIyMiUyMiUyQyUyMm9wdGlvbnMlMjIlM0ElN0IlMjJzaXplJTIyJTNBJTIyMTAlMjBpbmNoJTIyJTdEJTdEJTJDJTdCJTIyaWQlMjIlM0ElMjI2MDY2MjU5OTYlMjIlMkMlMjJxdWFudGl0eSUyMiUzQSUyMjYlMjIlMkMlMjJvcHRpb25zJTIyJTNBJTdCJTIyc2l6ZSUyMiUzQSUyMjYlMjBpbmNoJTIyJTdEJTdEJTVEJTdE
non functional output form console app:
JTdCJTIycHJvZHVjdHMlMjIlM0ElNUIlN0IlMjJpZCUyMiUzQSUyMjYwNjYyNTk5NiUyMiUyQyUyMnF1YW50aXR5JTIyJTNBJTIyMiUyMiUyQyUyMm9wdGlvbnMlMjIlM0ElN0IlMjJzaXplJTIyJTNBJTIyMTAlMjBpbmNoJTIyJTdEJTdEJTJDJTdCJTIycHJvZHVjdHMlMjIlM0ElNUIlN0IlMjJpZCUyMiUzQSUyMjYwNjYyNTk5NiUyMiUyQyUyMnF1YW50aXR5JTIyJTNBJTIyNiUyMiUyQyUyMm9wdGlvbnMlMjIlM0ElN0IlMjJzaXplJTIyJTNBJTIyNiUyMGluY2glMjIlN0QlN0QlNUQlN0A=
non functional output from qt app:
JTdCJTIycHJvZHVjdHMlMjIlM0ElNUIlN0IlMjJpZCUyMiUzQSUyMjYwNjYyNTk5NiUyMiUyQyUyMnF1YW50aXR5JTIyJTNBJTIyMiUyMiUyQyUyMm9wdGlvbnMlMjIlM0ElN0IlMjJzaXplJTIyJTNBJTIyMTAlMjBpbmNoJTIyJTdEJTdEJTJDJTdCJTIycHJvZHVjdHMlMjIlM0ElNUIlN0IlMjJpZCUyMiUzQSUyMjYwNjYyNTk5NiUyMiUyQyUyMnF1YW50aXR5JTIyJTNBJTIyNiUyMiUyQyUyMm9wdGlvbnMlMjIlM0ElN0IlMjJzaXplJTIyJTNBJTIyNiUyMGluY2glMjIlN0QlN0QlNUQlN0Q=
end of edit:
Ive written some code for a buyable link for my website. When I perform the same steps in google sheets it works perfectly every time, but when i wrote the application something isn't working and I'm at a bit of a loss. The code was reverse engineered from another free program i was using that has errors in the output all the time and in an effort to solve this problem I decoded the output and it (as far as i can tell) is json in this format {"products":[{"id":"intern. id #","quantity":"#","options":{"type":"option name"}}]}  with either the last two characters removed and a coma as a delimiter between the next set of this same template added i.e.{"products":[{"id":"intern. id #","quantity":"#","options":{"type":"option name"}},{"products":[{"id":"intern. id #","quantity":"#","options":{"type":"option name"}}]}. Then all of this is percent coded so it would look something like %5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22intern.+id+%23%22%2C%22quantity%22%3A%22%23%22%2C%22options%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22option+name%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22products%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22intern.+id+%23%22%2C%22quantity%22%3A%22%23%22%2C%22options%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22option+name%22%7D%7D%5D%7D, and then that's finally
encoded in base64 as i said i built this app in google sheets but its size is limited because google sheets can only be so big but i can do this very easily in c++ and qt and have a prety simple easy to use app. If i could figure out whats diffent. I should also say this code will open the cart but not fill it with anything or in some cases only fill it with the first thing in the list and im not understanding why
this is my driver code:
    #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>
    #include<sstream>
    #include<list>
    #include<string>
    #include<base64.h>
    #include<encoder.h>
    #include<infoFind.h>
    #include<escapencode.h>


    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {   
        list <string> choices;
        string done="";
        string internid="";
        string quant="";
        string type="";
        string option="";
        string open="https://www.sustainhydro.com/online-store/!/~/cart/create=";
        string body1="{\"products\":[{\"id\":\"";
        string body2="\",\"quantity\":\"";
        string body3="\",\"options\":{\"";
        string body4="\":\"";
        string body5="\"}}";
        string close="]}";
        string delim=",";
        string temp="";
        string comp="";
        string input="";


        while (done != "n")
        {
 
        catinfo();

        cout<< "" << '\n';
        cout << "Enter Internal Id: ";
        cin >> internid;
        cout << "Enter Quantity: ";
        cin >> quant;
        cout << "Enter Type: ";
        cin >> type;
        cout << "Enter Option: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin,option);

        cout <<""<<'\n';
        cout << "Do you have another SKU: y , n : ";
        cin >> done;

        temp=body1+internid+body2+quant+body3+type+body4+option+body5;
        choices.push_back(temp);
        choices.push_back(delim);



        if (done == "y")
        {
            continue;
        }  


        if (done == "n")
            {
                choices.pop_back();
                choices.push_back(close);
                for (auto i : choices)
                {
                    comp+=i;
                }

        if (!comp.empty() && (comp.back() == '\n' || comp.back() == '\0'))
            {
                comp.pop_back();
            }

            comp = escape(comp);
            cout << comp << endl;
            comp=base64_encode(comp);
            cout << comp << endl;

            cout << '\n';
            cout <<  "THIS IS YOUR URL:" << endl;
            cout << '\n';
            cout << open;
            cout << comp;
            cout << "" << '\n';
            cout << "" << '\n';
            cout << "Copy and Paste the URL From Here";
            cout << "" << '\n';
            break;

            }

        }


    return 0;
    }


custom header files to follow :
escapeencode.h
    #include<iterator>
    #include<algorithm>
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    #include<list>


    using namespace std;

    string space="%20";
    string colon="%3A";
    string bracko="%5B";
    string brackc="%5D";
    string braceo="%7B";
    string bracec="%7D";
    string quote="%22";
    string comma="%2C";


    string escape(string json)
    {
        list<string>temp;
        string result="";
        char chr;
        for(char i : json)
        {
            chr=i;
            string newchr(1,chr);
            if(newchr == "[")
            {
                newchr=bracko;
            }
            if(newchr == "]")
            {
                newchr=brackc;
            }
            if(newchr == " ")
            {
                newchr=space;
            }
            if(newchr == ":")
            {
                newchr=colon;
            }
            if(newchr == "{")
            {
                newchr=braceo;
            }
            if(newchr == "}")
            {
                newchr=bracec;
            }
            if(newchr == "\"")
            {
                newchr=quote;
            }
            if(newchr == ",")
            {
                newchr=comma;
            }
            temp.push_back(newchr);
        }
        for(string i : temp)
        {
            result=result+i;
        }

        return result;
    }

base64.h
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <array>
    #include <cctype>
    #include <string>


    const std::array<char, 64> base64_chars = {
 
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',

        'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',

        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',

        'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',

        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/'

    };


    std::string base64_encode(const std::string& input) {

        std::string output;

        int val = 0, valb = -6;

        for (unsigned char c : input) {

            val = (val << 8) + c;

            valb += 8;

            while (valb >= 0) {

                output.push_back(base64_chars[(val >> valb) & 0x3F]);

                valb -= 6;

            }

        }

        if (valb > -6) output.push_back(base64_chars[(val << (6 + valb)) & 0x3F]);

        while (output.size() % 4) output.push_back('=');

        return output;

    }


the same things are happening in my qt version and Ive used some of the code from this console application in my qt code as well if needed i can include that code as well i just didn't want to be to long winded here and i feel like i probably already have. Also cards on the table Im not a networking specialist or a website designer and im not the best coder out there i know that as far as the industry is concerned Im a shit coder.

You are aware that Qt has methods for a) creating JSON documents, b) base64encoding c) URL encoding, yes?  Have you compared the output against the original tool to see where it differs?

i am not aware that qt has tools for JSON although it doesn't surprise me, that said i haven't looked at the percent encoding through qt. Although i don't need a full on percent encoder as there are only a few characters that will ever need to be percent encoded, as the format only includes a few charterers, and since i already had a working encoder i just reused that code as it was easier to impalement that figuring out how to call the appropriate function and what headers need to be included etc.. i am using qt for the base64 part and im still having the same issue.

So figure out if a) the output is different from what you are trying to emulate and b) how it became different. Edit your question if you cannot figure out the second part.

also just a note i have run my template through a few other stand alone percent encoders and checked the output against mine and they are the same so i don't believe i have any issues there but I'm open to suggestions.

i have tried to figure out where the difference is and i think its in the base 64 part but im not a professional and i don't know exactly what is so different in the base 64 encoding ive tried running it through the working one i built in google sheets and checking a control string against my output and they are different i just don't understand why

Are you sure you're not messing up the JSON structure? You say it should be of the form {products: [PRODUCT1, {products: [PRODUCT2]}]}. Wouldn't {products: [PRODUCT1, PRODUCT2]} make a lot more sense?

i dont know json and im not 100% there isnt a better way what i know is thats how the program i was using strctured it and when i built it in google sheets it worked perfectly for every use case i tried and tested. and when i decode the output of that program that template is what underlies the percent encoding and base64 so thats what i used

Please edit your question with a correct base64 output and a wrong one. Debugging your issue will be vastly easier if we know where it is actually different.

ok ill do that.

ok i made the requested edits

As expected, the functioning base64 string decodes to:
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": "606625996",
      "quantity": "2",
      "options": {
        "size": "10 inch"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "606625996",
      "quantity": "6",
      "options": {
        "size": "6 inch"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Your console app generates an invalid %7@ at the end. If I remove that I still have invalid JSON, both syntactically (missing }}) and semantically (your second product is {products: PRODUCT} instead of PRODUCT).

ok ill double check my strings again and make sure their bing put togeather correctly  ....as im typing this i think i just realized what my screw up was thank you so much for humoring me i know its probably the dumbest mistake but sometimes a second pair of eyes is just super helpful ill do that double check and if it is what i think it is ill mark this as solved thanks again sooooo much !

im sorry i missunderstood the json question you asked in the begining and it just now hit me

thank you so much i know that was the dumbest mistake and such an easy over site but you saved the day for me ive been banging my head against a virtual wall trying to figure out what i did wrong and this works perfectly now you're awesome!

Messy code makes mistakes even harder to spot. If you were manipulating JSON objects instead of strings this would've stuck out like a sore thumb. Good you got it fixed!

yeah like i said i know im a shit coder and i get that i don't really know what im doing or understand most of this stuff the way a professional or someone that wasn't self taught would. I know that im just a pleb here. but im grateful none the less!
